# Русский текст C++

Tags: c++

Ввожу в строку русский текст. Получаю какую-то хрень. Хелпа

Comment: У вас проблемы с кодировками и/или со шрифтами. Для более дельного ответа нужны подробности. Где вводится, ось какая, файл ли это, в какой кодировке ввод, в какой вывод.

Answer (score 0):

Установите локаль языка.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
```